# Obtaining data from GET request and processing it (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am trying to obtain an array of information from a `GET` request in Angular 2. To do so, I created a service as follows:

```
obtainInformation() {
        // Obtain authorization token for the request
        const authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');

        // Configure headers
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('x-access-token', authToken);

        // Execute request
        return this.http.get(this.clubInfoUrl, { headers: headers })
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Then, I call this service from an `info.component.ts` as follows (for simplification I add only the exact part of the code):

```
this.service.obtainInformation()
    .subscribe(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    });
```

With this, I get an object with two strings and array of information (which is the array I want to process), but I am not sure about how I can pick the array.

I tried with `JSON.stringify()`, but then I cannot do (for example):

```
res.club_info.id
```

Notice that club_info is the array, and id is one of the elements of the array.

Any recommendation about it?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: output of `console.log(res)`

[Output of console.log(res)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2632.png)

[image]

Comment: Which output you got from : "console.log(res)" ?

Comment: I edited the post with the screenshot. Thank you!

Comment: you forgot `"0"` and the underscore before id

Comment: The tag for Angular 2 (which you have in the title) is `angular2`, not `angularjs` (which is for AngularJS 1.x). It's a bit unclear what your question is about though, so I didn't change them myself.

Comment: If I add it, I get an unexpected token [ error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include the index of the array when accessing.

You said:

> Notice that club_info is the array, and id is one of the elements of the array.

`club_info` is an Array. The first element of the array is a Javascript object, so you'll need to provide the array index to access the object. In addition, the attribute `id` does not exist, but perhaps you meant `id_number` or `_id`.

Thus, `res.club_info[0].id_number`

Comment: This worked fine, thank you! I am still learning so I did forgot the array index.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you got an array with 1 element:

you should call:

```
let first_element = res.club_info[0];

let first_element_id = first_element._id
```

Good Luck!